# How can I bind html tags according to response id?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, innerhtml

I have a response like this from backend : 
`

```
{ 
"data" :
        [
 {            
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "label" : 'Hello John',
 },
 {            
            "questionTypeId": 2,
            "label" : 'Hello John',
 },
{            
            "questionTypeId": 6,
            "label" : 'guided=true',
 },
{            
            "questionTypeId": 6,
            "label" : 'Follow',
 },
{            
            "questionTypeId": 6,
            "label" : 'create',
 },
{            
            "questionTypeId": 1,
            "label" : 'Hello Ria',
 },
{            
            "questionTypeId": 2,
            "label" : 'Thanks',
 },
{            
            "questionTypeId": 6,
            "label" : 'dear',
 },
{            
            "questionTypeId": 6,
            "label" : 'Mary',
 },
]
}
```

`

Now based on the questionTypeId, I have to bind that corresponding label to html tags.

suppose it is questionTypeId = 1, then i need to bind that label to `<h1>` tag in html.
and so on,

my problem is 
when i have questionTypeId = 6, which represents `<li>` tag
and i have to bind it to the  tag 
and that i have to bind only the continuous labels of questionTypeId = 6 to `<li>` tags

i.e for 6th element when questionTypeId becomes 1 then it should be the end of `</ul>` tag.

in HTMl ,
i kept

```
<div [innerHtml]="consentHtml">
      </div>
```

and in my .ts file

```
h1Header = `<h1 class="u-space-top--5 u-text-light">{0}</h1>`;
h5Header = `<h5>{0}</h5>`;
consentHtml = ``;
```

and then in for loop i kept switch statement to bind it to the html

```
switch (response.data[i].questionTypeId) {
            case 1:
              const b = this.h1Header.replace('{0}', response.data[i].value);
              this.consentHtml += b;
              break;
            case 2:
              const a = this.h5Header.replace('{0}', response.data[i].value);
              this.consentHtml += a;
              break;
          }
```

for h1 and h5 tags it working fine,
but i am not understanding how to bind `<ul>` and `<li>` tags

Please Can anybody help me out in this ?

Comment: Show me your HTML code, a minimal example required, give as an example how should like.

Comment: Hi George, I updated the question